# Rutas protegidas con React Router Dom V6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-redux

Estoy creando una aplicación en React utilizando react router dom v6. Para crear las rutas de la app estoy utilizando createBrowserRouter así

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/auth/*",
      element:<AuthRouter />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: authRoutes,
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <MainRouter />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: mainRoutes
    },
    {
      path: "/*",
      element: <Navigate to={'/'} /> ,
    },
  ]);

export const AppRouter = () => {
return (
    <RouterProvider router={ router } />
  )
}
```

Como hago para proteger mis rutas, dependiendo si el usuario está loggeado o no. Quiero mostrar las rutas de auth si no está loggeado y las de main si está loggeado. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? esto parece un Task, sugiero dar una revisión a [este vínculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)